# Why did nothing come out after "start without debugging"? And it showed " filenook.exe has triggered a breakpoint." after "start debugging"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, juce

This is a Juce project. It should show an .exe gui.

It showed " filenook.exe has triggered a breakpoint." after "start debugging"
in this line
jassert (success);

Download Juce framework here:
https://juce.com/get-juce/download

Whole project link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kxjIKCZqfALBe_Fpa9-WJSoXiN6JJe2t?usp=sharing

PluginEditor.h

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include "../JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h"
#include "PluginProcessor.h"
using namespace std;


class FilebookAudioProcessorEditor  : public AudioProcessorEditor
{
public:
    FilebookAudioProcessorEditor (FilebookAudioProcessor&);
    ~FilebookAudioProcessorEditor();

    //==============================================================================
    void paint (Graphics&) override;
    void resized() override;

private:
    // This reference is provided as a quick way for your editor to
    // access the processor object that created it.
    FilebookAudioProcessor& processor;
    TextEditor* text;
    File myFile;
    void openFileInEditor();
    JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (FilebookAudioProcessorEditor)
};
```

PluginEditor.cpp

```
#include "PluginProcessor.h"
#include "PluginEditor.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void FilebookAudioProcessorEditor::openFileInEditor()
{
    if (myFile.existsAsFile()) {
        text->setText(myFile.loadFileAsString());
    }
}
//==============================================================================
FilebookAudioProcessorEditor::FilebookAudioProcessorEditor (FilebookAudioProcessor& p)
    : AudioProcessorEditor (&p), processor (p)
{
    setSize (400, 300);
    text = new TextEditor ("Editor");
    addAndMakeVisible (text);
    text->setMultiLine (true);
    text->setReturnKeyStartsNewLine (true);
    myFile = ("C:\\filetest.txt");
    openFileInEditor ();
}

FilebookAudioProcessorEditor::~FilebookAudioProcessorEditor()
{
    deleteAllChildren();
}

//==============================================================================
void FilebookAudioProcessorEditor::paint (Graphics& g)
{
    // (Our component is opaque, so we must completely fill the background with a solid colour)
    g.fillAll (getLookAndFeel().findColour (ResizableWindow::backgroundColourId));

    g.setColour (Colours::white);
    g.setFont (15.0f);
    g.drawFittedText ("Hello World!", getLocalBounds(), Justification::centred, 1);
}

void FilebookAudioProcessorEditor::resized()
{
    text->setBounds (10,10,getWidth()-20,getHeight()-20);
}
```

JUCE is a partially open-source cross-platform C++ application framework, used for the development of desktop and mobile applications. JUCE is used in particular for its GUI and plug-ins libraries.

Comment: Without more information impossible to say. Why don’t you start with attaching a debugger to see what goes wrong?

Comment: Please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would appreciate it if you could show me `PluginProcessor.h`.

Comment: whole project link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kxjIKCZqfALBe_Fpa9-WJSoXiN6JJe2t?usp=sharing